# Using Marching Squares to connect curve ends in adjoining squares

Tags: algorithms, graphics

I'm learning Marching squares for a graphic program I'm working on and, while I understand how to connect points along an edge of a single square depending on the vertex values, I am unclear about how to connect two curves belonging to adjoining squares.

The part I'm trying to understand is this:
[image: Marching square image]
Say I'm linearly interpolating along edge `(a, b)` of Square X and there is a zero crossing somewhere after the midpoint `c` - let the zero crossing be at `0.75` along edge `ab`. This is point `f`.
To get rid of the ambiguity, I divide square Y into four squares - `Y1` through `Y4`. Now say while I interpolate along the smaller edge `ca`, I encounter a zero crossing before the midpoint of `ca` - let the zero crossing be at `0.25` of edge `ca`. This is point `g`.

1. How should I resolve the vertex values `(0 or 1)` of the squares?
2. How can I connect the two curve ends (in green)?